# Ставится ли запятая перед союзом "И"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Но, как видим, для Израиля границ не существует, и если израильтяне видят где-то угрозу, они в любом случае действуют сообразно собственным решениям.

После "и" разве не нужна запятая, как пишет Розенталь:

3) запятая ставится и перед союзом и, и после него, если он соединяет два простых предложения (причем после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза): Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера (М.-С.);

Answer (score 3):

Запятая здесь *нужна* и до, и после "и"; вторая - для двустороннего обособления последующего оборота. Это один из многих случаев, когда она явно противоречит интонации в пользу формальной разметки грамматических конструкций. Не нужна была бы запятая после "и" при наличии "то" после последней запятой (в качестве второй части союза "если... то"). Проверочным критерием по Розенталю является "изымаемость" обособленного оборота между двумя запятыми (его изъятие не должно приводить к разрушению смысла - иначе первая запятая не ставится).

Answer (score 2):

**Но, как видим, для Израиля границ не существует, и, если израильтяне видят где-то угрозу, они в любом случае действуют сообразно собственным решениям.**

**Формально запятая ставится,** что объясняется возможностью структурной перестановки придаточного при отсутствии двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО.

Однако в данном случае возможна **только структурная, а не семантическая перестановка.**

Попробуем переставить: Но, как видим, для Израиля границ не существует, и они в любом случае действуют сообразно собственным решениям, если израильтяне видят где-то угрозу.  **Не получилось!**

Конечно, по-хорошему **надо бы отказаться от такого формального подхода,** считать вторую часть единым СПП и запятую не ставить.

**Это было бы общим решением,** согласующимся и с наличием двойных союзов, то есть не надо делить СПП, если от этого затемняется смысл, **если с точки зрения семантики перестановка невозможна.**

У Розенталя есть на это "тонкие" намёки, например:

1) В предложениях типа Он давно уже уехал, и **где он теперь, я не знаю запятая** **после союза и не ставится.**   http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect110http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect110

2)  А женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, **хотя слова ее были привычными**, у Сабурова от них вдруг защемило сердце (Симонов) (при изъятии придаточного уступительного с союзом хотя предложно-местоименное сочетание от них **становится неясным**, но в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно, поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях **ОБЫЧНО** ставится).

Отсюда один шаг к "не обычному" решению.